# Failed to execute sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746 on project Project_Name

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, bitbucket-pipelines

I have build maven project using java 8 and doing all the pipeline and authentication configuration with Bit-bucket n Maven, but still getting this issue.

> Failed to execute goal
> org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar
> (default-cli) on project **Project name**

also getting this error message next line of error:

> The version of Java (1.8.0_121) you have used to run this analysis is deprecated and we will stop accepting it soon.

As Java 8 has been deprecated we are unable to get/view Sonar overview widget for our services.

Comment: add this in your properties hope it will work 'sonar.scanner.force-deprecated-java-version' to 'true'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned java 8 is been deprecated so You can force the analysis with Java 8 temporarily by setting the property

> 'sonar.scanner.force-deprecated-java-version' to 'true'.

in POM file like below

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <sonar.scanner.force-deprecated-java-version>true</sonar.scanner.force-deprecated-java-version>
</properties>
```

hope this will work.

You can find more information here: [sonar up-comings](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/upcoming/).

cheers.

Comment: it really helped I was entering this property in bitbucket-pipelines.yml file but somehow it was not helpful. Thanks